# How to use tkinter as ttk

Tags: python, tkinter, combobox, ttk

I am working on a big programme and I want Combobox to accept text only to be entered in it

I use This Code

```py
import tkinter
import ttk
import re
win = tkinter.Tk()
def num_only(num):
if str.isdecimal(num):
return True
elif num=="":
return True
else:
return False

def text_only(txt):
if re.match("^\[a-z\]*$",txt.lower()):
return True
elif re.match("^\[أ-ي\]*$",txt):
return True
elif txt == "":
return True
else:
return False
ttk.combobox(win,font="none 12 bold",validate="key",validatecommand(self.text_only,"%P"),values("value1","value2","value3","value4")
win.mainloop()
```

the validate don't work but it worked with tk.Entry

Comment: Please put your code in a code block

Answer (score 0):

ttk is a module of tkinter, so you have to import it like this:

```
from tkinter import ttk
```

Or instead of calling `ttk.Combobox` (note that python is case sensitive, so a call to `ttk.combobox` will not work), you can call it like

```
tkinter.ttk.Combobox
```

Also, according to [this post](https://tkdocs.com/shipman/entry-validation.html), you have to register your validate command using the .register method on your Tk object. That is, add the line: `text_only_Command = win.register(text_only)`, and call `text_only_Command` instead of `text_only`.

Finally, you have to pack your widget (so you need to create a Combobox object and then use the method `.pack()` on it)

Altogether, your code should look like this:

```
import tkinter 
# from tkinter import ttk 
import re 

win = tkinter.Tk() 

def num_only(num): 
    if str.isdecimal(num): return True 
    elif num=="": return True 
    else: return False

def text_only(txt): 
    if re.match("^[a-z]$",txt.lower()): return True 
    elif re.match("^[أ-ي]$",txt): return True 
    elif txt == "": return True
    else: return False 

text_only_Command = win.register(text_only)
num_only_Command = win.register(num_only)

combo = tkinter.ttk.Combobox(win, font="none 12 bold", validate="key",
                     validatecommand=(text_only_Command ,"%P"),
                     values=("value1","value2","value3","value4")) 
    
combo.pack()

win.mainloop()
```

Comment: Note that if you provide multiple characters, only the first one will be validated. If you want to allow for insertions, change `%P` for `%S`